# There has been an error processing your request product

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I import my products via **Magmi**, when I created my configurable product, and I'll find it on my site it shows me this error :

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 303608032

Comment: Please read the file named as 303608032 in the var/report/ folder and post a new question regarding the error contained in the first couple lines and post the stack trace. **There has been an error processing your request** is so generic a question as to be meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

These error messages are saved into **var/report** directory as a text file with the name being the error log record number. 
You have to open the file **var/report/303608032** to see the exception details.

Comment: Also to add to this, if you are testing on a non production site, it would be easier to debug issues by turning on error logging and setting php display_errors to on. If it is production then @Domeglic's method is the best.